# Loop Between 2 Dates with substruction a day each time of the loop

Tags: php, sql-server, date

I had make a function to retrieve data from the day x to day y What im trying to do is after fetching data from the Db i want to display the data for 30 days .
I have 2 dates, lets say they are:

from 2017-11-30 to 2017-11-01 . My statement is :

```
    $data['result'] = "200";
    $data['log'] = "success";

    $sql_activity = $sqlserver->prepare("select *  from t_email WITH (NOLOCK) where S_DATE>= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate()) and  FK_LIST= ?  ");
    $sql_activity->execute(array($_REQUEST['data']));
    $result_activity = $sql_activity->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


                foreach ($result_activity as $key => $value)
                {
                            $selected_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($value["S_DATE"]));

                            if( isset($data[$selected_date]) ) continue;

                            $data[$selected_date] = array();

                            $sql_unsub =  $sqlserver->prepare("select count(*) as nbunsub from t_email WITH (NOLOCK) where FK_LIST= ? and FK_EMAIL_UNSUB =1 and S_DATE between '".$selected_date."' and DATEADD (second, -1, DATEADD(day,1,'".$selected_date."'))");
                            $sql_unsub->execute(array($_REQUEST['data']));  
                            $result_unsub = $sql_unsub->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            $data[$selected_date]["unsub"] = $result_unsub['nbunsub'];
}


    echo json_encode ($data);
    exit;
```

the result is :

`{"result":"200","log":"success","2017-11-30":{"unsub":"0","spam":"0","soft-bounce":"0"}}`

Now i want to display data in this format :

`{"result":"200","log":"success","2017-11-30":{"unsub":"0","spam":"0","soft-bounce":"0"}}`

`{"result":"200","log":"success","2017-11-29":{"unsub":"0","spam":"0","soft-bounce":"0"}}`

`{"result":"200","log":"success","2017-11-28":{"unsub":"0","spam":"0","soft-bounce":"0"}}`

> . . .

`{"result":"200","log":"success","2017-11-01":{"unsub":"0","spam":"0","soft-bounce":"0"}}`

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @Ronnie this function display data like `{"result":"200","log":"success","2017-11-30":{"unsub":"0","spam":"0","soft-bounce":"0","hard-bounce":"444","nb_email":"997"}}` and i want to make loop for 30 days to get result like description bellow

Comment: are you asking how to make a loop? I still dont understand what the problem is.

Comment: well ,yes how to use loop from (today==>30days)  it dosen't work for me it return  Null , thx

Comment: jarrebtech GROUP_BY

Comment: @OmarElDon no it dosen't work

Comment: put the result inside the loop not out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $data['result'] = "200";
    $data['log'] = "success";

    $sql_activity = $sqlserver->prepare("select *  from t_email WITH (NOLOCK) where S_DATE>= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate()) and  FK_LIST= ?  ");
    $sql_activity->execute(array($_REQUEST['data']));
    $result_activity = $sql_activity->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $end = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $begin = clone $end;
    $begin->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('+31 day'));
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D') ,$end);

            foreach($daterange as $xyz)
            {
                foreach ($result_activity as $key => $value)
                {           
                        $selected_date = $xyz->format("Y-m-d");

                        if( isset($data[$selected_date]) ) continue;

                        $data[$selected_date] = array();

                            $sql_unsub =  $sqlserver->prepare("select count(*) as nbunsub from t_email WITH (NOLOCK) where FK_LIST= ? and FK_EMAIL_UNSUB =1 and S_DATE between '".$selected_date."' and DATEADD (second, -1, DATEADD(day,1,'".$selected_date."'))");
                            $sql_unsub->execute(array($_REQUEST['data']));  
                            $result_unsub = $sql_unsub->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            $data[$selected_date]["unsub"] = $result_unsub['nbunsub'];
               }
            }

    echo json_encode ($data);
    exit;
```